# using javascript function call to play multiple swf files

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using the following code to trigger the playing of a swf file when an image is clicked. It works great, but I want to have multiple swf files that are each triggered by diffent images.

```
<script language="JavaScript">
    function getFlashMovieObject(movieName)
    {
        if (window.document[movieName]) 
        {
            return window.document[movieName];
        }

        if (navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft Internet")==-1)
        {
            if (document.embeds && document.embeds[movieName])
                return document.embeds[movieName]; 
        }
        else // if (navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft Internet")!=-1)
        {
            return document.getElementById(movieName);
        }
    }

    function PlayFlashMovie()
    {
        var flashMovie=getFlashMovieObject("Flash1");
        flashMovie1.Play();     
    }
</script>
```

then the movie is triggered:

```
<div class="buttonimage1" style="background-color: #FFFFFF;">
<img src="icon1-small.png" alt="icon 1" onmousedown="PlayFlashMovie();" >
```

I want to add this so that (for example) clicking buttonimage2 would trigger "movie 2" and
buttonimage3 would trigger "movie 3" etc...

```
<div class="buttonimage2" style="background-color: #FFFFFF;">
<img src="icon2-small.png" alt="icon 1" onmousedown="PlayFlashMovie();" >
```

```
<div class="buttonimage3" style="background-color: #FFFFFF;">
<img src="icon3-small.png" alt="icon 1" onmousedown="PlayFlashMovie();" >
</div>
```

How can I set the getFlashMovieOject function for multiple movie names?
I've tried a couple of things but seem to be missing something and I'm pretty new to js.
A little help would be greatly appreciated. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have the `PlayFlashMovie` function take an argument:

```
function PlayFlashMovie(name) {
    var flashMovie=getFlashMovieObject(name);
    flashMovie.Play(); 
}
```

And then pass it like so:

```
<img src="icon1-small.png" alt="icon 1" onmousedown="PlayFlashMovie('Flash1');" >
<img src="icon2-small.png" alt="icon 2" onmousedown="PlayFlashMovie('Flash2');" >
```

etc

Comment: @WilliamSmith no, it's a parameter for the function. Look for errors in your developer console of firefox or chrome.