# Play multiple swf files on HTML web page

Tags: html, flash

I have developed web page with HTML and I have a place on the top of the page, where I play `.swf` file with embed control. My goal is to make it to play multiple `.swf` files (3 or 4 files) continuously.

How can I achieve this?

This is what I have:

```
<object width="311" height="100%" title="bn" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,28,0" classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-44953540000">
  <param value="../img/swf/main.swf" name="movie">
  <param value="high" name="quality">
  <param value="transparent" name="wmode">
  <embed width="311" height="100%" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/shockwave/download/download.cgi?P1_Prod_Version=ShockwaveFlash" quality="high" src="../img/swf/main.swf">
</object>
```

So I also have other `.swf` files, besides `main.swf`. Lets say I have `promo.swf`, `comm.swf`. I want to play all 3 of them continuously with 5 sec time stamp between each. For example, fist plays `main.swf` for 5 secs, after `promo.swf` and so on....

Comment: @shoshin Wont it play automatically?Please be more specific so that someone can help you. It is better if you post a snippet of what you tried already.

Comment: @A_AR I have updated my Question. I hope it is clear now. Can u pls check?

Comment: I suppose you can set the time for the flash program at design?

Comment: use javascript: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10986454/using-javascript-function-call-to-play-multiple-swf-files

Comment: It's not what  i want exactly. That post will change the flash file on mouseclick. But I want my files keep playing after 5 secs repeatedly. Can someone help please?

Comment: Dang it man! Can someone understand me correctly?!!! I just wanna play 3 different files within ONE `<object>` control. I want to change its' param every 5 secs. JUST LOOK AT MY QUESTIONS, if its too hard to understand.